# understand go unbuffered channel example

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

[official code example](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2)

```
func sum(s []int, c chan int) {
    sum := 0
    for _, v := range s {
        sum += v
    }
    c <- sum // send sum to c
}

func main() {
    s := []int{7, 2, 8, -9, 4, 0}
    c := make(chan int)
    go sum(s[:len(s)/2], c)
    go sum(s[len(s)/2:], c)
    x := <-c
    y := <-c
    fmt.Println(x, y, x+y)
}
```

printed : -5, 17, 12

why not printed 17, -5, 12 ?

I think x should be 17

Answer (score 1):

There's no defined order of which value gets written to the channel first, it's purely at the mercy of the scheduler. As all the example is doing is adding the results, it doesn't actually matter which way round the results turn up.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee in what order your `go sum(...)` goroutines will start and which will be the first to finish (and send to channel).